# Changing Item title

Tags: users

After giving permission to specific users to see the admin menu (those users can see only 2 items on the admin menu, items are 2 custom modules i've created) I'm trying now to change the items titles if the user is not the admin.

Example : admin can see : 'all users profils' (it shows list of all users)
but user A can see on the admin menu : 'my profil' where he can see only his profil (his profil is contained on the admin "all users profils"

this is my hook_menu_alter function :

```
function MyModule_menu_alter(&$items){

    global $user;
    if($user->uid = 1){ //if admin
    $items['admin/editor']['title'] = 'all profils';}
    else{ //if logged user
        $items['admin/editor']['title'] = 'My Profil'; //show same table but only with user information (not all users table)
    }

}
```

P.S. The code below show only one item

Answer (score 2):

Since the menu is already coming from your custom module, you do not need to implement hook_menu_alter, alter hooks are implemented to avoid hacking of core/contrib modules.

Back to your problem, assume your already implemented hook_menu looks like

```
  function mymodule_hook_menu() {
    $items['your/admin/menu'] = array(
      'title' => t('Test title'),
       // Add Title Callback 
      'title callback' => '_mymdoule_title_callback',
      'title arguments' => array(1),
      'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM,
      'access arguments' => array('access content'),
      'page callback' => 'function_content_callback',
    );
  }

/**
 * Title Callback for your Menu Item.
 */
function _mymdoule_title_callback() {
  global $user;
  if(in_array('administrator',$user->roles)) {
    return "Title for admin";
  }else {
    return "Title for non admin";
  }
}
```

Comment: I am glad it helped you!

Answer (score 0):

hook_menu_alter will only be called when the menu cache is cleared.

You can't use this method to change anything on a per-user basis.

I'd suggest you do this at the theme level, in your theme's template.php:

```
function MYTHEME_preprocess_menu_link(&$vars) {
  global $user;
  if($vars['element']['#href'] == 'admin/editor' && $user->uid != 1) $vars['element']['#title'] = "My Profile";
}
```

Comment: hi, you suggest me to add this function at template.php ?

Comment: Can I "force" the menu cache to be cleared ??

Comment: you could use cache_clear_all https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21cache.inc/function/cache_clear_all/7 to force the caches to clear, but this still wouldn't change the title per-user.

Comment: arpitr's answer is better anyway :)

Comment: Thank you andy I learned a lot about hook_menu_alter (y)